# Why would we need a new loop construct for-of in ES2015 when we already have for, forEach?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, foreach, ecmascript-6

I understand the concept that we always want to avoid the imperative way of loops when we use loop iteration variable `var i=0; i<length; i++` as it is very verbose and imperative way of doing things and provides us the index of items even when we don't need them. `.forEach()` method on array seems to be solving this by exposing `val` (and `index` only when needed) in a declarative approach:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
arr.forEach(function (val) {
  // Use val
});
```

I was going through ES6 constructs and have seen the new `for-of` loop construct. My questions after trying out is:

Why would we need a new construct when we already had 2 defined in the language? What functionality does it achieve which is not possible through the above 2 loop constructs?

Comment: To consistently iterate across iterables, for one thing.

Comment: `for..of` works with (potentially) infinite sequence generators. Can't do that with `.forEach()`.

Comment: The `for` loop is not verbose. I would also take issue with your characterization of `forEach` as "declarative"; it's (moderately) "functional" but still entirely procedural/imperative. A minor point, but the variable in `for...of` can be deconstructing, so you can write `for ([a, b] of pairs`).

Comment: forEach is counterintuitive - if for no other reason - that is .

Comment: You might want to glance over http://www.2ality.com/2012/06/for-of-ff13.html.

Comment: @torazaburo This artical definitely helped +1

Comment: Good reasons for using forEach were local variables, so temporary iteration variables didn't pollute the parent scope. This isn't the case since block scopes have been introduced. Still, array loop constructs differ in their performance, may be significant for demanding spots. Like for > forEach > for..of > for..in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why would we need a new construct when we already had 2 defined in the language? What functionality does it achieve which is not possible through the above 2 loop constructs?

You could make that argument for many new features in ES2015. Arrow functions, `let`, rest parameters, destructuring, etc. are more or less just syntactic sugar for things you can already do in JS. Tools like Babel, which convert ES2015 to ES5, prove that.

So, what's the point of syntactic sugar? To reduce boilerplate code and letting the engineer focus on *what* the code should do, rather than *how* it should do it.

---

As already noted, `for...of` works on any *iterable* (anything that implements a `[Symbol.iterator]` method that returns an iterator), not just arrays. Arrays simply are iterables as well.

`for...of` doesn't really introduce anything that couldn't be done with existing syntax (afaik). You can consume an iterator with a `while` loop.

```
for (var foo of bar) {
  // ...
}
```

would be equivalent to

```
var it = bar[Symbol.iterator](), next;
while ((next = it.next()).done !== false) {
  var foo = next.value;
  // ...
}
```

However, that isn't really easier to understand (or write). If we assume that iterables are supposed to become more popular / common, having better support to consume iterators seems reasonable.

Comment: So, the gist of the story is that ES6 has multiple types of collections/ iterables like Maps, Sets, Generators and its easier to consume the iterators using `for-of`. Right?

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

`forEach` exists on the `Array.prototype` but Arrays are not the only types that we iterate over. ES6 introduces many others and `for...of` provides a consistent way to implement a iterating behaviour for your custom types as well.

Answer (score -1):

The reason is more about convenience rather than addition any new feature. I wrote about this in my [Notes](https://github.com/SandeepTuniki/Notes/blob/master/javascript/ES6.md#for-loops) repo in Github. I'll paraphrase it directly here:

> Prior to ES5, for loops are written like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    // Do something
}
```

> In ES5, we can write it like this:

```
arr.forEach(function(elem) {
    // Do something
});
```

> The advantage of former is that we can break out of loops in the middle.
>   The advantage of latter is conciseness.
>   ES6 combines both of them and introduces new syntax called **for-of**:

```
for (let elem of arr) {
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: I would disagree almost entirely. It's not at all about convenience; it's about supporting the entire notion of iterables in ES6. Also, I would not say that the advantage of `forEach` is conciseness (at least not exclusively). Then, your final example is wrong--this won't work at all as you seem to think it will. The only way to maintain an index with `for..of` is to maintain it yourself.

Comment: @torazaburo, you are right about the indexing part. I must've misunderstood it. I'll remove it.